# How to establish the scalar-multiple and the triangle inequalities as properties of the norm in the completion?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

For a normed space  $(X, ||.||)$, we can find a Banach space $\hat{X}$ which has a dense suspace $W$ that is isometric with $X$; and this space $\hat{X}$ is unique except for isometries.

Now while proving this famous result, how to establish these two properties of the norm for the space $\hat{X}$?

1. $ || \alpha \hat{x} || = |\alpha| \cdot ||\hat{x}|| $ for any $\hat{x}$ in $\hat{X}$ and scalar $\alpha$.
2. $||\hat{x}+\hat{y}|| \leq ||\hat{x}||+||\hat{y}||$ for any vectors $\hat{x}$, $\hat{y}$ in $\hat{X}$.

Comment: The technical details will depend a lot on the choice of the concrete construction of $\hat{X}$ you want to use, so it would be helpful to know which one you are familiar with.

Comment: I'm covering Theorme 2.3-2 in Erwine Kryszig's "Introductiory Functional Analysis With Applications" and am stumped at the very last sentence in the proof given by the author. He just states that the scalar-multiple and the triangle inequality for the norm on $\hat{X}$ follow from those of the norm on $W$ by a limit proces. I would like to be able to fill in the details as to exactly how the above statement is true. In other words, I want to establish the same facts rigorously.

Comment: I don't have Kreyszig's book, so I'm not sure how he defines $\hat{X}$ (is $\hat{X}$ the completion of $X$ as a metric space via equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences?). It seems like the theorem in [this blog post](http://drexel28.wordpress.com/2010/11/03/) might help.